# tor browser bundle + sshuttle safe together?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, vpn, transparent-proxy, ssh

I started using [sshuttle](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle) as "poor man's VPN over SSH" to forward all the outgoing tcp traffic / dns query to a private server.

> sshuttle allows you to create a VPN connection from your machine to
>   any remote server that you can connect to via ssh, as long as that
>   server has python 2.3 or higher. To work, you must have root access on
>   the local machine, but you can have a normal account on the server.

I wonder if browsing the web using Tor Browser Bundle + sshuttle can screw up anonymity or have negative side effects. Any idea?